# Scraping pandas Code hard

Tags: python, pandas

La url que utilizo es del archivo html que descargue de este vinculo: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NzgjsD-fIPkVLjFMfu0bBpruwFoZd-LM

```
from pandas import pd

def Leer_html():
    try:
        url = "file:///C:/Users/ronye/Downloads/fuenteDeDatos.html"
        dfs = pd.read_html(url)
        print(dfs)
    except:
        print("Error: sin internet; perdida de conexión")
```

muy bien, pero lo que quiero es poder mostrar cierto dato de cualquier columna o fila.
Pero no he encontrado información necesaria para poder lograrlo, ese es mi problema.

Comment: ¿Ese título? Intenta poner otro que refleje lo que estás preguntando, como por ejemplo "Seleccionar filas o columnas de una tabla html usando pandas"

Comment: Entonces tu problema no es con el *scraping*, sino que no sabes cómo tratar un *dataframe* con pandas. Revisa la [documentación al respecto](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics). No hay atajos.

Answer (score 0):

Un par de cosas sobre `pandas.read_html()`. Esta función intenta buscar en el documento HTML que le pases todas las tablas (elementos `<table>`) que contenga, y para cada uno de ellos te genera un dataframe pandas. Lo que retorna finalmente es una **lista de dataframes**.

Aún en el caso en que el HTML sólo tenga una tabla, te retornará igualmente una lista (si bien con un solo elemento). Deberías quedarte con el elemento `[0]`  de lo que retorne tu función, que contendría el dataframe correspondiente a la primera tabla del documento (y única en tu caso).

Por otro lado, el HTML del documento en cuestión no sigue el convenio de utilizar elementos de tipo "table header" (`<th>`) para marcar lo que serían los títulos de las columnas, sino que mete esos títulos en la primera fila del cuerpo de la tabla (`<tbody>`). Así que pandas por defecto trataría esa primera fila como datos, en lugar de tratarla como lo que es, las cabeceras de los datos.

Puedes corregir esto al cargar el documento, así:

```
    dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
```

que le dice a pandas que use la fila 0 de los datos como cabecera.

Haciendo esto, el dataframe que cargas parece correcto:

```
>>> dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
>>> df = dfs[0]
>>> df
```

[image: tabla]

Una vez tienes el dataframe correctamente cargado lo de acceder a una fila o columna es seguir el mecanismo clásico usado por pandas. Dices que no has encontrado información, pero sin embargo eso es lo básico de pandas. No sé qué fuentes habrás consultado. Hay muchos libros, tutoriales, y notebooks de ejemplo que puedes encontrar en internet que suelen comenzar precisamente por cómo seleccionar filas y columnas. También tienes [propio manual de pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Para empezar por algo:

- Seleccionar una columna, si la columna no tiene espacios o símbolos raros en el nombre, puede hacerse usando una sintaxis sencilla:

```
>>> df.Detalle
0               Propiedad en Cartago 1200 mtrs
1                         Servidor HP Proliant
2               Central Telefónica Avaya 2700u
3                  Televisor Sony 55" KDV55021
4                   iPhone X -125 G - Gerencia
5          Vehiculo Toyota 2014 - Modelo Yaris
6    25 Licencias de Windows 10 ES PRO 64 bits
7                            Camión Isuzu 2008
8                         Mobiliario 25 sillas
9                           SAP One on Premise
Name: Detalle, dtype: object
```

- Si tiene espacios en el nombre, pon el nombre entre comillas y usalo como si fuera la clave de un diccionario python, es decir:

```
>>> df["Fecha de compra"]
0    15/02/2010
1    01/01/2019
2    31/11/2015
3    21/10/2017
4    10/05/2018
5    23/08/2014
6    26/03/2015
7    05/06/2008
8    10/10/2015
9    22/01/2018
Name: Fecha de compra, dtype: object
```

- Para seleccionar filas, usa el atributo `.loc` y pon entre corchetes el índice de la fila (en este caso te devuelve una serie cuyos índices son las columnas de esa fila):

```
>>> df.loc[1]
Identificador                              2342
Categoria                                   AFT
Detalle                    Servidor HP Proliant
Valor inicial                           7689300
Fecha de compra                      01/01/2019
Moneda                                  Colones
Valor de salvamento                      450000
Periodo de recuperacion                       6
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

- Puedes seleccionar una "sub-tabla" especificando dentro del `.loc`, separados por comas, el rango de filas y el rango de columnas, o una lista con la selección de columnas que te interese. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> df.loc[0:3, ["Categoria", "Fecha de compra", "Moneda"]]
```

[image: Resultado]